# Unable to match up the column name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm searching for the column name but my code is not working. This is what I have tried :

```
    word = "sample"
    Set aCell = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=word, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    lastRow = Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For k = 0 To lastRow
        If aCell Is Nothing Then
            aCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next k
```

All I want to do is to delete the entire column if it is found. Any help ?

Comment: aCell.EntireColumn.delete if there is a range, something found, in aCell.  You will need to loop the find until it returns nothing.  Should lastRow, be lastColumn :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
Sub deleteColumn()

Dim headerColumnToDelete As String
Dim endRow As Integer
Dim counter As Integer

endRow = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
headerColumnToDelete = "sample"

For counter = endRow To 1 Step -1

    If Cells(1, counter) = headerColumnToDelete Then
        Cells(1, counter).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If

Next counter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the whole column with the column heading "sample", try this in a Module:

```
Public Sub DeleteSample()

    DeleteColumn ("sample")

End Sub

Public Sub DeleteColumn(Name As String)

    'Get the header row
    Dim row As Range
    Set row = Rows(1)

    'Find the cell containing Name in that row
    Dim result As Range
    Set result = row.Find(Name)

    Dim wholeColumn As Range

    'Select the whole column (or quit if it's not found)

    On Error GoTo Catch
    Set wholeColumn = result.EntireColumn()
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Delete the whole column and shift cells left
    wholeColumn.Delete xlShiftToLeft

Catch:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

You don't need a For-loop at all, you can just use the Excel API to find the cell :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub columndelete()
    Dim lastcolumn As Long
    word = "sample"
    lastcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To lastcolumn
        If Cells(1, i).Value = word Then
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just made some changes in your code:

```
Sub test()
    word = "sample"
    Set acell = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=word, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not (acell Is Nothing) Then
        acell.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```